# OpenFileDialog C#, allow user to type file name?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the `OpenFileDialog` to let the user choose a file.

However, I also want the user to be able to type a file name in the box that shows the file name selected and create that file if it does not exist....

Right now, if I type a file name and click the open button it says that file does not exist...

Is it possible to do that with `OpenFileDialog`? thanks

Comment: How can you open a file that does not exists???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> create that file if it does not exist

It sounds like you need to use the `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: Boom Tim I feel stupid, thanks for your suggestion, I could use SaveFileDialog

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you set `OpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists = false` and `.CheckPathExists = false` before showing the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `OpenFileDialog.CheckFileExists = false` and `OpenFileDialog.CheckPathExists = false` works for WPF also!