# Export text to a browsed file in wpf

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I'm trying to export some text to a file browsed by the user and create it if this file does not exists.
What I've done till now is to use OpenFileDialog but I don't know if it's the right way to do it and also if it is I don't know how to continue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenFileDialog C#, allow user to type file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068671/openfiledialog-c-allow-user-to-type-file-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SaveFileDialog()`

```
    var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
    var path = dialog.FileName;
    File.WriteAllText(path, "YourData");
```